# How to prevent Ubuntu from checking for updates on startup?

Tags: updates, 22.04, update-manager

Every time I boot my 22.04, it's checking for updates and eating into my monthly cellular traffic limit. It's really annoying, and I tried a bunch of proposed solutions, none of which work fully. How to actually stop it from doing that, short of blocking the hosts that it's contacting? I want to retain the ability to update manually, just prevent it from checking updates on boot.

Answer (score 4):

Open the settings of that connection and mark it as **Metered**!

[image: Network Settings Window showing Metered connection option]

Comment: (+1) Does that also prevent snap and flatpak updates indefinitely?

Comment: That's a good one, thank you, I have not seen this advice before when researching this topic.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi snapd and unattended-upgrades (deb) are supposed to respect the Metered setting. Have not checked on flatpak. Any package manager that fails to respect the Metered setting should be reported as a bug in that application.

Comment: It was already set to metered, so it doesn't work. Doesn't work against snap either.

Comment: Last time I tested Metered connections, it worked properly to stop both deb and snap automatic connections. Might be a bug. Might be something else.

Answer (score 2):

I have just discovered that it was `packagekitd` service doing that. I've already stopped and disabled it in the past, so that didn't help permanently, but now I've also `mask`ed it. Hopefully, that's the end of that.

```
sudo systemctl stop packagekit.service
sudo systemctl mask packagekit.service
sudo systemctl stop packagekit-offline-update.service
sudo systemctl mask packgekit-offline-update.service
```

Comment: @user535733 There is no bug here, and even if there was it would not be with PackageKit. The described behavior is the way systemd was designed combined with how a majority of distros (including Ubuntu) actually handle unit file updates (they reload and then re-sync presets, so if the unit was configured to be enabled by default, it will be re-enabled each time the package it’s in was updated), and masking the unit is intended to override this (and things like socket activation starting it). It’s admittedly questionable behavior, but that doesn’t make it a bug.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn fair enough that Packagekit would not be the proper target of a bug report. And fair enough about how systemd and updates work. But automatic updates over a metered connection (a setting that explicitly claims the behavior won't happen) still seems like unexpected behavior worthy of a report.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Software & Sources`, and disable automatic check for updates. Also disable installing security upgrades in the background automatically.

[image]

---

If you use snap apps, you cannot disable their background updates, so consider replacing all the snap apps with APT packages.

Comment: That, unfortunately, won't stop SNAP, FlatPack or other package managers.

Comment: These are all disabled. Also, I have disabled snapd separately, the problem is not with that, it's with the Ubuntu's native software updater.